# Spark 2.3 - Log4j Vunlerability

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

In our project, running spark 2.3 with 7 nodes.
Recently as part of Security scan, log4j vulnerability is reported by security Team.
We can see log4j 1.x jar in the spark folder (/opt/spark/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar).
We tried to replace the jar with log4j 2.17.1 version and tried to run the spark. But Spark is failing with "NoClassDefFoundError" for class org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Upgrade your Spark cluster. This has been fixed in Spark3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using log4j-1.2-api of version 2.17.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api

Comment: You cannot simply replace log4j1 with log4j2. The imports are different

Comment: @OneCricketeer: `log4j-1.2-api` (aka Log4j 1.x Bridge) provides a replacement for the original Log4j 1.x classes that redirect the output to Log4j2.

Comment: Do we need to give below configurations ? “log4j1.compatibility” to a value of “true” and  “log4j.configuration” to the location of the log4j 1 configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy 3 jars(core,api,bridge) from https://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/ and put in spark/jar folder.

Refer this page for details.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html